# Why alertify confirm cancel button not working?

Tags: javascript, jsp, alertify, alertifyjs

I am using `alertify.confirm()` in my spring mvc project.

```
alertify.confirm(
    "Press OK to Confirm",
    function(){ console.log("ok") },
    function(){ console.log("canceled") });
```

But whenever i press `OK` or `CANCEL` button, it prints "ok" in the console. Why is this happening?

Comment: yes but can be overloaded with `alertify.confirm(message, onok, oncancel);`

Comment: **onCancel**  .... typo @Dai

Answer (score 0):

[Alertify's `confirm` has **four parameters**](https://alertifyjs.com/confirm.html), not three: `title: string, message: string, onOK: function, onCancel: function )`

Change your code to this:

```
alertify.confirm(
    /*title:  */ "Confirm low-effort stackoverflow posting"
    /*message:*/ "Press OK to Confirm posting a question to stackoverflow without doing a quick 15-seconds google search",
    /*ok:     */ function(){ console.log("ok") },
    /*cancel: */ function(){ console.log("canceled, good, the world is better for you having done your research first") }
);
```

---

I **do** see an [overload with 3 parameters in their documentation page](https://alertifyjs.com/confirm.html), [however the source-code of Alertify's `confirm.js][2]` re-uses the `onok` parameter for `oncancel` - I think that's a bug:

```
main: function (_title, _message, _onok, _oncancel) {
                var title, message, onok, oncancel;
                switch (arguments.length) {
                case 1:
                    message = _title;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    message = _title;
                    onok = _message;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    message = _title;
                    onok = _message;
                    oncancel = _onok;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    title = _title;
                    message = _message;
                    onok = _onok;
                    oncancel = _oncancel;
                    break;
                }
                this.set('title', title);
                this.set('message', message);
                this.set('onok', onok);
                this.set('oncancel', oncancel);
                return this;
            },
```

Given that AlertifyJS [hasn't been significantly updated **in six years**](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/AlertifyJS/tree/master/src/js), I think you should consider using a different dialog library. [Consider using native HTML5 `<dialog>` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog).

Comment: I did check the documentation first. I got error with four parameters. `alertify.min-63a08ef1e1e49d82efcc98b21c1b98ae.js:2 Uncaught Error: fn must be a function
    at Object.dialog (alertify.min-63a08ef1e1e49d82efcc98b21c1b98ae.js:2)` . Thats why i tried with three parameters.

Comment: @mahfujasif The error you posted shows you're using a minified version of `alertify` which may have been altered by the minification process. What happens if you use a non-minified version that you can use with a step-through debugger?

Comment: @mahfujasif But honestly, I think you should just ditch Alertify.js because it's so old. Why are you using it?